# hashmap and arraylist connected

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

My main purpose is to make my arraylist and hashmap always connected.
Connected in the sense means if I add any thing in map then it should be copied in `ArrayList` and viceversa.
Any idea guys.

```
static Map<Integer,Employee> emp = new HashMap<Integer,Person>();
static ArrayList<Employee> ls = new ArrayList <Employee>(emp.values());
```

by this code whatever I add in `HashMap` is getting copied in list,but when I remove from `ArrayList` it's not reflecting in map.
pls help.

Comment: You should tag your question with the particular programming language you are using. I guess its Java.

Comment: yes its java language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `emp.values()` collection. It is backed up by the map and vice-verca. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values()

`Collection<Employee> ls = emp.values();`

If you remove something from this `Collection`, it will be removed from the `HashMap` as well.
In your example you are creating a new `ArrayList` and copying the reference of all elements into it. Of course this new `ArrayList` has no idea of you `HashMap`.

A short example:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "One");
map.put(2, "Two");
map.put(3, "Three");

// Output is "{1=One, 2=Two, 3=Three}"
System.out.println(map);

Collection<String> backedUpCollection = map.values();

// Remove something from collection and check the maps content
backedUpCollection.remove("Two");

// Output is "{1=One, 3=Three}"; "Two" was removed
System.out.println(map);

// Add an entry to the map and check the content of collection
map.put(4, "Four");

// Output is "[One, Three, Four]"; "Four" was added
System.out.println(backedUpCollection);
```

Comment: I have used that only...but its working only one way round.Like list values are updated but I want that map should be also updated if I alter list.

Comment: If you remove something from the list, it should be removed from the maps as well. Of course it is not possible to add something to the list, since you cannot provide the key, which the map needs.

Comment: No I think thats sufficient. Do you really need a `ArrayList`? This `Collection` should be working.

Comment: I am taking arraylist because I cannot delete a whole object Employee by map directly with EmployeeId.

Comment: My structure:Employee-->id,name and map's key is an auto increment integer.

Comment: And you want to delete an Employee by EmployeeId? Stupid question: Why don't you use the ID as map key? Using an autoincremented integer as map key does not seem very reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Connected in the sense means if I add any thing in map then it should be copied in ArrayList and viceversa.

But lets say that you add something to the array list, what would you want the key to be for the hash map?

Once you decide on the behavior for each use case, the solution that I suggest is to write your own add and delete functions, which always add/remove values from both the array and the hash. Then you can use those methods, which wrap around the methods provided by Java, instead of using them directly.